# how to load pdf with ctrl+p from a webpage

Tags: javascript, printing

I'm wondering if there is a way to load a PDF when a user hits ctrl+p on a webpage. Is this something that you need to do in javascript or something else? (Basically I have an html page and a pdf flyer with the same information. I want people to see the html page on screen but print the flyer.) And yes, I know I can make a print page button but I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
function doc_keyDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80) {
    // call print code here.
    console.log('PRINT PDF.');
  }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', doc_keyDown, false);
```

It is a basic key event binding on the page, I could have provided a PDF file with print but it will not work on SO because of the CORS issue.